# Redirect but keep url in address bar

Tags: apache, .htaccess, proxy, redirect, plesk

I am trying to redirect a page from demo.example.com to demo1.example.com but to keep the demo.example.com in the url address bar (I own both of the domains). I read that in order to do that I need to use mod_proxy but I dont know where I should write rules and what I should write. I tried with .htaccess but not luck:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*) http://demo1.example.com/$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```

In my apache services I have the following options:

```
proxy 
proxy_ajp 
proxy_balancer
proxy_connect 
proxy_express 
proxy_fcgi 
proxy_fdpass 
proxy_ftp 
proxy_html 
proxy_http
proxy_scgi 
proxy_wstunnel
```

I am using ubuntu server with apache and plesk

Answer (score 2):

In most of the cases .htaccess should looks like:

```
RewriteEngine  on
RequestHeader set Host demo1.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://demo1.example.com/$1 [P,L]
```

It requires rewrite, proxy, proxy_http and headers modules.

If it doesn't work check all(really all, not just logs of demo1.example.com) web server logs on server which host demo1.example.com, because your request can be catch by some another virtual server.